# How to achieve Android UI like this image layout? About android:clipChildren

Tags: android-layout, android, android-xml

What I want to achieve is like this layout:
[image]

I have tried to use this code, to achieve like that image, but unfortunately, I failed.
This is the snippet of my code:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        >



        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_area_third"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corner_background"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_download_purch_third"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/acron_icon"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="1asdasdasdasdadsasdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/acron_icon"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/acron"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </RelativeLayout>

         <LinearLayout
             android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_area_third"
             android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/text_area_third"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@color/orange"
             android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
             android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
             android:padding="3dp" >

             <TextView
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:text="GET"
                 android:textColor="@color/white"
                 android:textSize="13sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold" />
         </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

You can see that, the "GET" label(with orange background) is clipped through the parent bound. I have set the `android:clipChildren="false"`, but still it is clipped. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What happens if you align it to the parent layout(using `layout_alignParentTop/Left`) instead of `text_area_third`(And adjust the `layout_marginLeft/Top` accordingly)?

Comment: @Geobits: i've tried that too, but the same error happened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single RelativeLayout is the way to go. Remember to keep things as simple as possible. In RelativeLayout the last declared elements are rendered on top of the others. The XML below should (kinda) fit your needs, just adjust images and margins and sizes as you require.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="#DDD" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_download_purch_third"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corner_background"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
        android:paddingRight="25dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="1asdasdasdasdadsasdasdadasdasdasdasdasdasdasdasd"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/acron_icon"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/acron"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="#FFA0A0"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="GET!"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using FrameLayout?? That makes the overlaying of image easier... (making one layout/view appear on top of another)... Here is a good tutorial...

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_frame-layout/

Comment: [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) should never be used to hold more than one child.

Comment: the document says its okay to use it if you don't care about different screen resolution..

Comment: @Eric: can you elaborate more about the reason why `FrameLayout` is not supposed to be used to hold more than 1 child?

Comment: If you look at the FrameLayout description on developer.android.com  [Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)

Comment: FrameLayout is in fact an excellent base to create custom lightweight ViewGroups holding an unlimited number of children. Many Android widgets do this: ViewSwitcher, ImageSwitcher, TextSwitcher, ...