# CardView ignoring android:clipChildren="false"

Tags: android, android-cardview, margin

I want to have a CardView which contains an ImageView which overlaps the left border of the CardView.
I want to do this by giving the ImageView a negative margin.
This works fine with all other layouts (LinearLayout/RelativeLayout/FrameLayout) by setting clipChildren="false".

However I can't get it to work with a CardView.
The ImageView will be clipped and does not overlap the CardView.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:clipChildren="false">
    <ImageView
           android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
           android:background="@drawable/some_picture"
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: why don't you put imageview outside the cardView, and then put both of them in a RelativeLayout overlapping each other?

Comment: Would be an option. However having the ImageView inside of the CardView feels like the cleaner solution to me.

Comment: Check out his link, hope it helps...

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845891/how-to-achieve-android-ui-like-this-image-layout-about-androidclipchildren

Comment: Thank you. But as I wrote: I know that it works fine with everything else than CardViews. I would like to use CardViews though.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution or a workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [clipChildren is not working even though set to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930626/clipchildren-is-not-working-even-though-set-to-false)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, this seems to be a problem only with Android 5+, the solution is to set

```
cardView.setClipToOutline(false);
```

Source - https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/2tccge/cant_draw_outside_of_cardview_parent/

Comment: Not the problem only with 5.0, Lower version also its not working. This solution only support api level 21 and above. What is the solution for below version.

Comment: SOLUTION:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/53654808/294884

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your MaterialCardView xml file

```
android:outlineProvider="none"
```

Comment: Works, but removes shadow (for androidx.cardview.widget.CardView at least).

Answer (score 1):

wrap it in `LinearLayout` with param LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:clipChildren="false">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

to CardView's grandfather View.